Best-known explicit binary error-correcting codes
I am exploring explicit constructions of binary linear error-correcting codes and particularly interested in finding explicit linear codes that come closest to achieve:

Distance: $d = O(log(n))$.
Rate: $r = 1 - \frac{O(\log(n))}{n}$.

I assume that such a linear code is not known. What is the best rate I can achieve as long as the distance is $O(log(n))$?

BCH has rate $1 - \frac{O(\log(n)^2)}n$, if I understand correctly, as does the binary Goppa code

Reed-Muller also gets this rate
